# Lambda expression: reference to lambda inside lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I've a little trouble understanding this expression, particulary, why an error is not thrown since at the time of defining lambda, lambda reference itself is only just being declared. Interestingly it also works in a recursive way. I would expect L is not defined Error. Is this perhaps because of implicit variable hoisting? (python moving variable declarations to the top/start of current scope)

```
#why doesn't this throw an error
L = lambda: print(L)

#recursive example...
L = lambda: L()
```

Comment: Lambdas work like any other function definition; the names in them don't need to be resolvable until they're called. Otherwise you couldn't have recursive functions at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#why doesn't this throw an error
L = lambda: print(L)
```

Here you are only defining an anonymous function and storing its address in L, Not executing the logic here. 
You can assign the lambda function to a variable to give it a name. Exactly what you did in the above mentioned code

`>>> lambda: print(x)
<function <lambda> at 0x7f17e201b9d8>`

In the above example as you can see the logic is not executed but a function address is returned. Now if we try to run it:

`>>> a = lambda: print(x)
\>>> a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

You can see once we tried to execute the logic it broke with the message you were expecting.

And now why your code didn't break is that once it executed in the last line by calling `L()`, L was already defined as shown bellow:

```
#why doesn't this throw an error
L = lambda: print("Here is the L i defined just in this line: {}".format(L))
>>> L
<function <lambda> at 0x7fc345e4e9d8>
>>> L()
Here is the L i defined just in this line: <function <lambda> at 0x7f6b12ad79d8>


#recursive example...
L = lambda: L()
```

If i call `L()`, i would get a recursion error because the function keeps calling it self over and over again

> > > RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: It was bothering me that it is defined AND used in the same line... since usually what is on the right side of assignment is executed first, then assigned. So techincally when the execution of right side of = is running, it doesn't know yet it will be assigned to L, and L is not defined yet in that "moment"